# Does the existence of a linear functional on $C_0^\infty(\mathbb R)$ which is not a distribution require the axiom of choice?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory, axiom-of-choice, hamel-basis

Consider $C_0^\infty(\mathbb R)$ as a real vector space. By choice, we can take a Hamel basis $\{e_\alpha\}_\alpha$ for $C_0^\infty(\mathbb R)$ such that every $f\in \mathbb C_0^\infty(\mathbb R)$ can be written as

$$f=\displaystyle\sum_\alpha c_\alpha e_\alpha, \quad c_\alpha \in \mathbb C.$$

Let $\{U_j\}_{j\geq 1}$ be a neighborhood basis to $0\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb R)$ in topology induced by open balls with respect to the local metric

$$d(\varphi_1, \varphi_2) := \displaystyle\sum_k 2^{-k} \frac{\|\varphi_1 - \varphi_2\|_k}{1+\|\varphi_1-\varphi_2\|_k}$$

where $$\|\varphi\|_k := \displaystyle \sum_{\alpha\leq k} \sup_{x\in K} |\partial^\alpha \varphi|, \quad \|\varphi\| := d(\varphi, 0).$$

The locality of the metric should be interpreted as defining the metric for test functions with support contained in a compact set $K \subseteq \mathbb R$.

Take now $ e_1\in \{e_α\}_α$ and $t\in \mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ such that $t e_1 \in U_1$ and set

$$ g_1:=te_1.$$

Continue to choose $g_j\in U_j$ in the same manner. Then, by construction, all $g_j$ are linear independent and $\{ g_j\}_j$ a part of a Hamel basis. Now define the map $\lambda : C_0^\infty(\mathbb R)→\mathbb C$ with
$$\lambda(g_j):= j$$
and extend $\lambda$ by linearity to be a linear map. Then $\lambda$ cannot be a distribution, since we have

$$g_j \to 0$$

in the topology on $C_0^\infty(\mathbb R)$ as defined above, but

$$\lambda(g_j) \not\to 0$$ as $\lambda$ will be an unbounded operator on any neighbourhood $U$ to $0\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb R)$.

So we have that

**AoC implies the existence of a linear functional on $C_0^\infty(\mathbb R)$ which is not a distribution.**

But does it require choice?

Comment: This definitely doesn't imply choice. Your proof uses axiom of choice for a very particular set (or two, since the extension of  $\lambda$ uses choice as well). There is no way this implies full choice. A better question is whether existence of such a linear functional can be proven without the use of AC.

Comment: Nothing, *ever*, which depends on a single, specific set is equivalent to choice.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks! As mentioned above, it probably makes more sense to ask if the result depends on choice!

Comment: Yes, that would be a much better question, I reckon.

Comment: But let me ask this first, is your question really asking about linear functionals which are discontinuous? Because if so, this was asked before. Yes, choice is necessary.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I assume you mean continuity in the sense that if a sequence of test functions $\{\varphi_j\}$ converges strongly (uniformly with all its derivates) to 0, then $u(\varphi_j) \to 0$.

Comment: Well, I mean, there is a topology on that space, right? Which makes it some "reasonable TVS"... no?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Locally on $\mathbb R$ there is a topology, yes.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I have looked for potential duplicates but didn't find a result which would answer the question for *this particular* topological vector space. Have I missed something (some general statement implying this)?

Comment: @Wojowu: I don't think *this* specific space was mentioned, no. But if we insist that each space is specifically mentioned for it to be a duplicate, then infinitely many questions will have the same answer. If it's close enough and the answer is comprehensive enough, I don't see an issue with it being a duplicate.

Comment: Markus, what do you mean, locally on $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila The metric is not defined for all test functions, just for test functions with support in a compact subset of $\mathbb R.$

Comment: I, personally, *would* insist on demanding a duplicate with this exact space, or a sufficiently similar one. The space of test functions and its continuous dual, the space of distributions, are central to the theory of distributions, and I imagine it is a question which has occured to many students whether there are functionals which *aren't* continuous (indeed, this exact question was asked a number of times on this site). Asking whether choice is necessary *in this particular case* seems like a sensible specific question to me.

Comment: @Wojowu: So asking for the derivative of $\sin$ and that of $\cos$ are two completely different questions? Nonsense. But let's not get into meta talks here...

Comment: Results by Wright in "All operators on a Hilbert space are bounded" provide a hint towards a *yes* answer: he proves that it is consistent with ZF+DC (indeed, follows from ZF+DC+"all sets of reals have the Baire property") that every linear functional on a Fréchet space is continuous. The space in question, however, is not Fréchet (it's not even metrizable, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2359213/127263)). However, this gives us, for instance, that every linear functional on the Schwartz space is a tempered distribution.

Comment: @Wojowu: Better source would be Garnir's "*Solovay’s axiom and functional analysis*" (MR 0477688) where the context is far broader than Banach or Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Also Eric Schechter's book Handbook of Analysis and its Foundations is a wonderful source for choice related stuff in analysis.